# Is there a way to have stroke for UIFont

Tags: ios

I'm using MKMap with overlay. The overlay display text. I need the text to have "stroke" effect. any clue?

```
[t drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,30) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" /*"Arial"*/ size:(3 * MKRoadWidthAtZoomScale(zoomScale))] 
     ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're drawing in `drawRect:`, you can set the text drawing mode using:

```
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGTextStroke);
```

If you wanted to fill and stroke, then you can use `kCGTextFillStroke`.

Comment: I tried to follow your answer, but it didn't show the stroke, code below:  CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor ); 
   CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor redColor].CGColor );
    
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(ctx, kCGTextFill);
     CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(ctx, kCGTextFillStroke);
     [t drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,30) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" /*"Arial"*/ size:(3 * MKRoadWidthAtZoomScale(zoomScale))]

Comment: That's really weird...I copied and pasted your code into a UIView subclass in an empty project and it worked. The only thing I changed was I replaced t and fontSize (due to not being able to use them). Is it possible t is an empty string or (3 * MKRoadWidthAtZoomScale(zoomScale)) is zero?

Comment: Oh by the way, you have two set text drawing modes. You only need one since the first one will get replaced by the second one.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an `CFAttributedString` from your string, set appropriate `kCTStrokeWidthAttributeName` and `kCTStrokeColorAttributeName` attribute values and draw it with `CoreText` framework.